# Fill same color into different contour in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, contour, image-segmentation

I have two binary circles of one object.They don't connect together. I finished fill color for a circle. Now, I want to fill same color into two circles that don't connect together. This is my code. But it does work. Could you edit help me please?

```
  figure
  [xx yy] = meshgrid(1:384,1:384);
  phi1 = (sqrt(((xx - 190).^2 + (yy - 260).^2 )) - 15);
  phi2 = (sqrt(((xx - 270).^2 + (yy - 200).^2 )) - 20);
  phi= sign(phi1).*sign(phi2);
  phi(phi==-1)=0;
  imshow(phi);
  cont = contourc(phi, [0 0])';
  cont = cont(2 : end, :);
  patch(cont(:, 1), cont(:, 2), 'g', 'EdgeColor', 'w')
```

Comment: I see that you have two circles defined by phi1 and phi2. Then I am not quite sure what you are trying to do. Are you trying to fill two circles with the same color?

Comment: @ysakamoto yes sir. i only try to make a object that are created by phi1 and phi2 such that they don't connect together

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little script to draw a filled circle. You can make it into a function and use `hold on` and `hold off` to draw many circles.

```
r = 2;
xc = 1;
yc = 1;

st = r/100;

x1 = (-r+xc):st:(r+xc);
y1 = yc+sqrt(r^2-(x1-xc).^2);
x2 = x1(end:-1:1);
y2 = yc-sqrt(r^2-(x2-xc).^2);

x = [x1 x2];
y = [y1 y2];

patch(x,y,'g','FaceColor', 'g');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a more general shape using implicit definition of the curve, the following works too:

```
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(1:384,1:384);

phi1 = 15^2 < ((xx-190).^2 + (yy-260).^2);
phi2 = 20^2 < ((xx-270).^2 + (yy-200).^2);
phi = phi1 .* phi2;

contourf(phi, [0,1]);
colormap([0,1,0;1,1,1]);
```